# Google Charts axis start

Tags: google-visualization

Below is url that chart I am using.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chco=99C754&chs=400x150&chds=20,1&chd=t:1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|12/07/09|12/14/09|12/21/09|12/28/09|01/04/10&1:1|10|20&chxr=1,20,0,10&chls=2&chg=25,100,1,2&chm=o,54C7C5,0,-1,5&chxtc=1,15|0,15

I want to start y-axis from 1 but in my chart is started from 0.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

little look at google 
show :

> Axis Range ***chxr*** :
>   You can specify the
>   range of values that appear on each
>   axis independently, using the chxr
>   parameter. Note that this does not
>   change the scale of the chart
>   elements, only the scale of the axis
>   labels. If you want to make the axis
>   numbers describe the actual data
>   values, set  and 
>   to the lower and upper values of your
>   data format range, respectively. See
>   Axis Scaling for more information.
>
> You must make an axis visible using
>   the chxt parameter if you want to
>   specify its range.
>
> To specify custom axis values, use the
>   chxl parameter.

http://code.google.com/intl/iw/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#axis_range